# fread issues on windows 7 64 bits

Tags: c++, windows-7, binary, fread

I'm trying to create a part in my program to write a binary file. It seems to work find but to be sure, I created an other part wich read this binary when I close the file.

Here come issues. I use the fopen/fwrite/fread functions and visual studio 12 with a Windows seven 64 bit and it seems that fread doesn't work correctly on Windows (I tried to read on linux, no problem and when I copy / paste the code, it compiles but the values I get are bad).

Here my code to read:

```
int     en;
float   fl;
double  dl;
char    c;
FILE    *F;
int     cpt;

cpt = 0;
if ((F = fopen("SimpleTest.twd", "rb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("error on fopen\n");
    return ;
}
while (cpt < 9)
{
    fread(&fl, 4, 1, F);
    printf("%f\n", fl);
    cpt++;
}
```

I included cstdlib and cstdio and I'm sure of the existence of SimpleTest and the location of the file.

Thank

Comment: I don't see a question in your "Question"... Could you tell us what values are in the file, and what values you are getting? And complete code that compiles would be good...

Comment: 'fread doesn't work correctly on Windows' - I kinda doubt that.

Comment: Sorry, well I have a matrix with the values 100 010 001 in my file, in binary (float) and when I get my floats, I have 0 0 0 -3.15756 0 -3.15756

Comment: This is how I write : fwrite(&x1, 4, 1, test); where x1 is a float and test = "SimpleTest.twd"

And I have no doubt about the fact thet fread works correctly on windows, it's just that I don't understand why this code works on linux but not on windows.

Comment: @user2720969 you can edit your question and amend the code, and *please use **real** code* that compiles. "It something like..." and such generally skip the real issues. (case in point, your last comment, `test` *better* be a `FILE*` and not a string literal).

Comment: What is sizeof(double), and how much are you reading?  Default float is double?